# how do i integrate an svg script with iframe on a webpage?

Tags: javascript

Bare with me I'm a n00b....

I'm working on a project and the person that has the drupal knowledge has backed out making me responsible for their part.

ISSUE:
I'm in the works of creating an intercative map [uoft-medicine.eu.pn](http://uoft-medicine.eu.pn/) using snap svg, now I have to integrate it into their website using iFrame;

1) how do i go about iframing my svg script?

2) how to i implement it into their working prototype site?

the map wont be changing on demand, it will probably stay the same until the new school year.

Comment: Is this about Drupal?